# Update Jenkins failed to connect afterward

Tags: jenkins, post-update

I'm having a nightmare trying to update our Jenkins server. We are using a Debian VM to host our server. Last time it was updated was 2 years ago. So I have cloned the VM in case of trouble (thank god cause there is). I downloaded the newest war file and moved it to /usr/share/jenkins and done:

```
service jenkins stop
service jenkins start
```

I'm updating from 2.190.3 with java 8 still installed.

From there, I tried to go on my browser to check the update was done and end-up with a 502 bad gateway page.

When I try:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ version
```

I get:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1226)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1162)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1056)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:990)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1340)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1315)
        at hudson.cli.FullDuplexHttpStream.<init>(FullDuplexHttpStream.java:71)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.plainHttpConnection(CLI.java:279)
        at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:271)
        at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:83)
```

But when I check status of Jenkins:

```
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sat 2021-06-26 12:26:17 BST; 1min 9s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2269 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/jenkins stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2308 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

So I am a bit confused. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a big jump, especially over 2.277.1. Have you read the [change-log](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/) and the [upgrade guide](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/). You need to examine the Jenkins logs for more info to see if it's really fully running.

Comment: @ianW I have indeed and I don't think it is the problem, I will though try and update to a closer version to see if it is. I looked at the page to install jenkins and it suggest java 11 to install the latest version should I upgrade my java ? could it be the issue?

Comment: Stick to Java 8 for now; while most ppl report no issues, it is not th e recommended or default yet. Try update all plugins, then go to 2.263.4 first, update plugins again, then 2.277.1 plugins again, then latest.

Comment: Appeared that moving the new war file was not the move to do. Instead after following the installation steps for debian worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following these [steps](https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian/) instead of downloading the war file and moving it.